# Keras: get numeric value of tensor element

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensor

I'm trying to make a custom loss function which returns different values depending on the range of the predicted and real values. But I **can't compare the values because the variables are tensors, and I can't find a way to get their only element numeric value** (my output is 1-dimentional). I thought this would be a simple task, but I have tried a lot of things (converting to numpy array, converting to list, getting the norm, getting the minimum, using eval) and nothing works.

Here's my code*:

```py
def myloss(y, h):
    if 0.5 < y < 0.7 and 0.5 < h < 0.7:  # LINE 2
        return 0
    return abs(y - h)
   
def custom_loss(target, pred):
    return kb.mean(kb.map_fn(lambda e: myloss(e[0], e[1]), [target, pred]))
```

Line 2 is where I need the values (y and h are tensors like `Tensor("custom_loss/map/while/TensorArrayV2Read/TensorListGetItem:0", shape=(1,), dtype=int64)`).

If I run that, I get the error

> TypeError: Expected int64 passed to parameter 'y' of op 'Greater', got 0.5 of type 'float' instead. Error: Expected int64, got 0.5 of type 'float' instead.

Here's a minimal example on **Colab***: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1CA7GCU-dfh-zrdTPAt-tLNTJpz8n2rN4#scrollTo=OPGlDAEAaosM. Feel free to edit and test.

[*] I have simplified the function for readability.

Comment: Please include the reproducible code on Stack Overflow and not on a third-party website.

Answer (score 0):

Cast to float:

```
def myloss(y, h):
    y = tf.cast(y, tf.float32)
    if tf.constant(0.5) < y < tf.constant(0.7) and tf.constant(0.5) < h < tf.constant(0.7):  # LINE 2
        return 0. # <= add dot here
    return abs(y - h)
```

Comment: It still says ```OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed: AutoGraph did convert this function. This might indicate you are trying to use an unsupported feature.```

Comment: Same error. If I simplify the condition to `if y > tf.constant(0.5):`, it says ```TypeError: 'retval_' has dtype int32 in the main branch, but dtype float32 in the else branch```.

Comment: @Raphael see the edited answer (add dot after zero)